# Convert integer to binary and print the sum of the digits

Tags: java, binary

The code below is supposed to take an integer, convert it to binary, and then print the sum of the digits:

Example:

```
Input = 15 

( 15 in Binary is "1111" and 1+1+1+1 = 4 )

Output = 4
```

This is the code I have so far. However, it is not working as expected. If you input `15`, it returns `0` instead of `4` as explained above:

```
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  int X = in.nextInt();

  String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(X);   

  int amount = 0;  
  String input = Integer.toString(X);

  for(int b = 0; b < binary.length(); b++){
     if (binary.charAt(b) == 1){
      amount++;
     }
  }

  System.out.println(amount);
```

Comment: What happens? What do you expect?

Comment: You'll encourage responses if you provide a range of your sample inputs, and what happened as a result.  That way the question can be answered more quickly as the issue might be obvious without as much walking the logic and/or compiling and coming up with test cases ourselves.   (Or put more succinctly, '+1 what @GernotKrost' said while I was typing. :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Characters are always single and written in single quotes.**

1 is the character which is extracted from String and it should be written in single quotes.

Here is the correct code:

```
if (binary.charAt(b) == '1'){
  amount++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shorter approach:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int X = in.nextInt();
String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(X);   
String input = Integer.toString(X)
System.out.println(StringUtils.countMatches(input, "1"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Binary operations are enougth

```
    int p = 0b10000000000000000000000000010101;
    int t = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<32; i++) {
        t += p & 1;
        p = p >> 1;
    }
    System.out.println(t);
```